# bash script: check if all words from one file are contained in another, otherwise issue error

Tags: bash, compare, diff

I was wondering if you could help. I am new to bash scripting.

I want to be able to compare two lists. File1.txt will contain a list of a lot of parameters and file2.txt will only contain a section of those parameters.

File1.txt

```
dbipAddress=192.168.175.130
QAGENT_QCF=AGENT_QCF
QADJUST_INVENTORY_Q=ADJUST_INVENTORY_Q
QCREATE_ORDER_Q=CREATE_ORDER_Q
QLOAD_INVENTORY_Q=LOAD_INVENTORY_Q
```

File2.txt

```
AGENT_QCF
ADJUST_INVENTORY_Q
CREATE_ORDER_Q
```

I want to check if all the Qs in file1.txt are contained in file2.txt (after the `=`). If they aren't, then the bash script should stop and `echo` a message.

So, in the example above the script should stop as File2.txt does not contain the following Q: `LOAD_INVENTORY_Q`.

The Qs in file1.txt or file2.txt do not follow any particular order.

Comment: Interesting problem! Just to clarify: You want to find EACH item in file2.txt in a line in file1.txt, with an "=" sign right in front of it. Do you care that there is nothing after? I suspect not, since there might be comments etc.

Comment: You are correct sir. Well though there would always be something after the equals sign. I will review all the answers tonight as I have been pretty busy thank you all for the responses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command will print out lines in file1.txt with values (anything appearing after `=`) that do not appear in file2.txt.

```
[me@home]$ awk -F= 'FNR==NR{keys[$0];next};!($2 in keys)' file2.txt file1.txt
dbipAddress=192.168.175.130
QLOAD_INVENTORY_Q=LOAD_INVENTORY_Q
```

Breakdown of the command:

```
awk -F= 'FNR==NR{keys[$0];next};!($2 in keys)' file2.txt file1.txt
    ---  ---------------------- -------------
     |           |                    |
change the       |               Target lines in file1.txt where
delimiter        |               the second column (delimited by `=`) do
  to '='         |               not exist in the keys[] array.
           Store each line in    
           file2.txt as a key
           in the keys[] array
```

To do something more elaborate, say if you wish to run the command as a pre-filter to make sure the file is valid before proceeding with your script, you can use:

```
awk -F= 'FNR==NR{K[$0];N++;next};!($2 in K) {print "Line "(NR-N)": "$0; E++};END{exit E}' file2.txt file1.txt
ERRS=$?
if [ $ERRS -ne 0 ]; then  
    # errors found, do something ...
fi
```

That will print out all lines (including line numbers) in file1.txt that do not meet the bill, and returns an exit code that matches the number of non-conforming lines. That way your script can detect the errors easily by checking `$?` and respond accordingly.

Example output:

```
[me@home]$ awk -F= 'FNR==NR{K[$0];N++;next};!($2 in K) {print "Line "(NR-N)": "$0;E++};END{exit E}' file2.txt file1.txt
Line 1: dbipAddress=192.168.175.130
Line 5: QLOAD_INVENTORY_Q=LOAD_INVENTORY_Q
[me@home]$ echo $?
2
```

Comment: I like the way you provide an exit code that gives the number of missing items.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` to get only the part after `=`. `comm` can be used to output the lines contained in the first file but not the second one:

```
grep ^Q File1.txt | cut -d= -f2- | sort | comm -23 - <(sort File2.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command line expression will filter out the lines that occur in file2.txt but not file1.txt:

```
cat file1.txt | grep -Fvf file2.txt | grep '^Q'
```

explanation:

```
-F : match patterns exactly (no expansion etc.) ; much faster
-v : only print lines that don't match
-f : get your patterns from the file specified

| grep '^Q' : pipe the output into grep, and look for lines that start with "Q"
```

This isn't exactly "stop the bash script when..." since it will process and print every mismatch; also, it doesn't test that there's an "=" in front of the pattern - but I hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the relevant lines in `file1.txt` always start with a `Q`:

```
grep "^Q" file1.txt | while IFS= read -r line
do
    what=${line#*=}
    grep -Fxq "$what" file2.txt || echo "error: $what not found"
done
```

Output:

```
error: LOAD_INVENTORY_Q not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
missing=($(comm -23 <(awk -F= '/^Q/ {print $2}' file1.txt | sort) <(sort file2.txt)))
if (( ${#missing[@]} )); then
  echo >&2 "The following items are missing from file2.txt:"
  printf '%s\n' "${missing[@]}"
  exit 1
fi
```